# How to check if HW raid is active?

Tags: 18.04, mount, hard-drive, raid

I have just set up Ubuntu 18.04 with HDD in a JBOD setup from an old win10 install.

I tried once to setup HW raid but it didn't work in win10 so I didn't bother anymore with it. But after I installed 18.04 it seems that 2 of the disks are in raid setup kind of. Since when I try to mount them with Ubuntu's "disks" utility, I can only mount one a the time. If I first mount disk X to folder 1 and disk Y to folder 2 afterwards the config for disk X gets overridden to the same as disk Y. Therefore I think there is some kind of hardware raid setup that works for Ubuntu but not for Windows it seems.

How can I easily check this?
I have tried lsscsi without seeing a clear way to them being in raid.

[image: sudo lsblk]

Comment: Can you include the output of `sudo lsblk`?

Comment: Added picture, I can see that I find the drive i'm "missing" on ssd and the other on sdc.

Comment: There's nothing indicating any kind of RAID there.